# Jquery on page load with local storage default option not set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are multiple posts out there for setting the default option using Jquery.

But i tried most of them, but not seems to be working.

Guess something wrong with my condition?

I just need to get the the default option `Article Type` on page load.

**Code:**

```
<select id="blogarticletype">
<option selected><?php echo $this->__('Article Type') ?></option>
                <option><?php echo $this->__('All Types') ?></option>
                <!--Begin To Retain Article type drop down in local storage after refresh-->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        if (localStorage.getItem('mySelectLocalstorageValue') === null) { 
                            localStorage.setItem('mySelectLocalstorageValue', "articletype");
                            //document.write("All Types"); 
                        }
                        else {
                            if (localStorage.getItem('mySelectLocalstorageValue') === "article") { 
                                document.write("Articles"); 
                            } else if (localStorage.getItem('mySelectLocalstorageValue') === "makers") { 
                                document.write("Artists & Makers"); 
                        }
                </script>
</select>
```

On page load:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#blogarticletype option:selected').text();


if (jQuery('#blogarticletype').length) {
    jQuery('#blogarticletype').val(localStorage.getItem("mySelectLocalstorageValue"));
}


});
```

But when page loads, i get empty value shown in the drop down.

If i manually set in the inspect for option value as `selected="selected"` then it shows, but not on page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is change on this line

```
$('#blogarticletype [value='+localStorage.getItem("mySelectLocalstorageValue")+']').attr('selected', 'true');
```

and it works. Working Demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/Qxvjmz